# Cite a book in general and then a chapter in particular

Tags: citations, scientific-publishing

The question is in the context of a paper and a thesis in the area of computational science, computer science and chemistry. I manage my references with Mendeley, and import them into a LaTeX file using Bibtex.

In the introduction, I cite a book about the general approach used in that research project. Later on, in a section about methods and computer implementation, I'd like to refer to a specific chapter in that book from where some algorithms were taken.

**What's the correct way to cite that book in general and then the chapter in particular?**

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily off topic here, but you might want to check out also [academia.se] if you haven't already.

Comment: Can you let us know what style guide you are using for references e.g. APA?

Comment: If it's in the text body I'd prefer page numbers. If it's in the reference list it completely depends on the style. Did you ask your supervisor?

Comment: You may also find some help in [English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/citation)

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention the format (APA, MLA, Harvard etc.) required so I'm going to chose APA for you.

Here's how I approached the question:

- Opened google.com
- Searched for 'Mendeley'
- Typed 'citations' in the search box for Mendeley (top search result)
- In the new search results, clicked on 'How to Cite Sources in APA Citation Format - Mendeley' (third result, but there are also options for MLA and Harvard)
- Searched within the page for 'chapter'
- Found the following (second result):

> How to Cite a Chapter in an Edited Book in APA Format
>
> Edited books are collations of chapters written by different authors.
>   To reference a single chapter, a different format is needed. The basic
>   structure is as follows:
>
> Edited book chapter example:
>
> In the following example, B.N. Troy is the author of the chapter and
>   S.T. Williams is the editor.
>
> Troy, B.N. (2015). APA citation rules. In S.T, Williams (Ed.). A guide
>   to citation rules (2nd ed., pp. 50-95). New York, NY: Publishers.

If your book has one author rather than an editor then simply omit 'S.T, Williams (Ed.).'.

This isn't really my answer per se, but I hope you benefit by it.

Source: https://www.mendeley.com/guides/apa-citation-guide

Answer (score 2):

Here's a specific reference to the style used by the eighth edition of the *MLA Handbook* (3.3.3):

> If the work is divided into stable numbered sections like chapters,
>   the numbers of those sections may be cited, with a label identifying
>   the type of part that is numbered.
>
> According to Hazel Rowley, Franklin and Eleanor Roosevelt began their
>   honeymoon with a week's stay at Hyde Park (ch. 2).
>
> Part numbers in any source should be cited only if they are explicit
>   (visible in the document) and fixed (the same for all users of the
>   document). Do not count unnumbered parts manually. A source without
>   page numbers or any other form of explicit, fixed part number must be
>   cited as a whole; include in the text or in a parenthesis enough
>   information for the reader to find the corresponding entry in the
>   words-cited list—usually the author's last name.

This is an in-text reference to a chapter in a book that's in a works-cited list. As far as I can tell, works-cited entries do not, themselves, include references to chapters.

As for the format of the entry for the book itself in the works-cited list, it would, in general, look like this:

> Rowley, Hazel. *Some Book Title*. Some publisher, date.

The question cannot be answered more specifically without more information. (The style to use, additional relevant information about the specific book, and so on.)